# How to detect collisions for a complex object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-development

How should I detect collisions for a sprite that can't have a rectangular hitbox? I am trying to make a platformer, and I'm currently working on collision detections for the level's platforms. Here's my physics:

```
function onTimerTick() {
  if (moveY > 300) {
    momentumY = momentumY - 2;
    move(moveX, moveY);
  } else if (moveY < 300) {
    moveY = 300;
    momentumY = 0;
    move(moveX, moveY);
  }
  moveY = moveY + momentumY;
  move(moveX, moveY);
  if (moveY <= 300) {
    if (momentumX > 0) {
      right = true;
      momentumX -= 1;

    } else if (momentumX < 0) {
      if (document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").getAttribute("scr") != "walkLeft.gif") {
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "walkLeft.gif";
      }
      right = false;
      momentumX += 1;

    } else {
      if (right == true) {
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "amaincharacter.png";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "maincharacterleft.png";
      }
    }
    moveX = moveX + momentumX;
  } else {
    moveX += momentumX / 3 + 1;
    document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "jumpmain.gif";
  }
  document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = momentumX;
}
```

I'm thinking of trying to break up the level into different rectangles, all in the same class, and then test for collisions within that class. Is there any way I could do this? Also, I think I should use boundingClientRect, but I don't know how to use this for collisions.

Comment: I added an idea, but I don't know how to actually make it.